# How to make bar plot using this data

Tags: r

I want to develop a bar plot using this data with the same of columns as shown in the data.

| Valley | Female | Young | Yearling | Class1 | Class2 | Class3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hushey | 144 | 160 | 162 | 24 | 18 | 29 |

I tried this code, it produce the bar plot but with changed order of columns. developing bar plot using pivot_longer function, which produced graph but also changed the order of columns.

```r
ibex %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Valley) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Valley) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "", x="", y="Number of Ibex sighted")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using this code to develop the bar plot:                                                                         
   ibex %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Valley) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(~Valley)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(0))+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title = "",x="",y="Number of Ibex sighted")

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the code there in a code block (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189 for formatting in questions). Code in comments formats poorly, and comments are often skipped by readers and/or hidden (when many) by the Stack interface. (I'll edit your code in for now, please do it yourself in the future.) Thanks!

Comment: If you want to change the order of things in ggplot2, it relies very much on the lexicographic (alphabetic) sort of strings. To control the order, use `factor`, such as `ibex %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Valley) %>% mutate(name = factor(name, levels=name))` (and then your plotting code).